# Javascript map object literal does not work but new Object() works

Tags: javascript

Does the Object literal notation not work inside map function? I tried this in Node 12 and 15 REPL

```
> nums = [1,2,3,4]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
> nums.map(n => { n })
[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
> nums.map(n => new Object({n}))
[ { n: 1 }, { n: 2 }, { n: 3 }, { n: 4 } ]
```

Comment: `nums.map(n => ({ n }))`. Without the `()`, the `{}` is considered as a code block, not as an object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
nums.map(n => ({ n }))
```

Without the parentheses, `{ n }` is being interpreted as the body of your function. By including parentheses, you're indicating that `{ n }` should be implicitly returned instead.

[Here](https://waylonwalker.com/explicit-vs-implicit-returns-in-javascript/) is an overview of implicit vs. explicit returns, which should help provide some more detail.

Comment: oh god, thank you, is there a link to that paranthesis usage to understand it better?

Comment: @sgarg please check the duplicates linked above your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/38015233

Comment: cool, found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003702/what-do-the-parentheses-wrapping-the-object-literal-in-an-arrow-function-mean/45003753